# DecimalFormat depending on system settings?

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I'm having the strangest thing with a DecimalFormat.

I'm using it in an webapplication.
I setup some test and it keeps on failing with me locally.
A friend of me ran it and he was able to successfully ran the JUnit tests.

The strange part is that on our server the application runs it perfectly without any problems either.

Could it be that Java depends on the system settings like valuta and number settings?
Or could there be another reason?
This is how my piece of code looks like:

```
public String generateFormatPrice(double price) throws Exception {
    DecimalFormat format1 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    String tmp = format1.format(price).replace(".", "&");
    String[] tmps = tmp.split("&");
    return tmps[0].replace(',', '.') + "," + tmps[1];
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The first sentence of the Javadocs for [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) mention locale. Also, where is the code for the failing unit test?

Comment: It probably would be a good idea to state how the tests fail. Is an exception generated? If so, what exception? Is the output different from what you expect, causing a JUnit assertion to fail? If so, what output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: "To obtain a NumberFormat for a specific locale, including the default locale, call one of NumberFormat's factory methods, such as getInstance(). In general, do not call the DecimalFormat constructors directly, since the NumberFormat factory methods may return subclasses other than DecimalFormat. If you need to customize the format object, do something like this:

 NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
 if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
     ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
 }"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code is indeed locale-specific. If your code depends on being in a locale such as the USA where "." is the decimal separator and "," is the thousands separator, and then you run this code on a server set to, for example, the German locale, it will fail.

Consider using this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols%29), which allows you to explicitly specify which symbols you are using.

EDIT: as far as I can tell you are trying to format numbers using "." as the thousands separator and "," as the decimal separator. In other words, the format used in France and Germany. Here's one approach that will achieve this:

```
public static String generateFormatPrice(double price) {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    return format.format(price);
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using a double to hold a monetary value - you are going to encounter some nasty bugs if you do that.