# Different representations of DecimalFormat grouping symbol

Tags: java, junit, locale

Today I discovered a locale-problem in the next code listing. My goal is to format numbers with swiss german locale (de-CH) so that thousands are separated with apostrophes (') and decimals with period (.). According to [ICU](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/de-CH/index.html) this is the default for that country's locale.

```
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

assertEquals("1'000.2", format.format(1000.2455));
```

This works as expected on my colleagues machines that use swiss german locale. However, when I run it on my machine with US locale, the test fails as the group separator is ’ and not ' ([apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe)).

```
expected:<1[']000.2> but was:<1[’]000.2>
Expected :1'000.2
Actual   :1’000.2
```

Through another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743252/1297789) I found that I can access and modify the DecimalFormat to achieve my goal. While the unit test is satisfied with this result, I am not. From the [DecimalFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) I don't understand why the grouping symbol deviated from the expected thousands separator. As it is the same character, the only culprit I see is the IDE (or rather the Font its using).

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf('’'));
39
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf('\''));
8217
```

My question is: how can I write the unit test so it is not vulnerable to different representations of the same character?

Comment: Why do you write JUnit tests testing JDK's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

The Java output using `’` (not `'`) as the thousands separator looks correct to me, for the Swiss German locale. The ICU documentation and Java also refer to `’`.

Given this, your unit test does not have to be concerned with different representations of the thousands separator - unless you explicitly want to use `'`, not `’`.

### Background

The two different characters are:

- `'` - standard keyboard apostrophe (Unicode [U+0027](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm))
- `’` - right single quotation mark (Unicode [U+2019](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm))

According to the locale page linked to in the question ([the de-CH locale page here](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/de-CH/index.html)), the number grouping separator is `'` - the standard apostrophe.

However, I think this documentation is possibly incorrect - or, at least, misleading - in the context of your question.

The Java [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object takes its language subtag values from the [IANA Language Subtag Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

The registry entry for Swiss German is this:

```
Type: language
Subtag: gsw
Description: Swiss German
Description: Alemannic
Description: Alsatian
Added: 2006-03-08
Suppress-Script: Latn
```

So, we build a Java locale for Swiss German using "gsw" as follows:

```
Locale swissGermanLocale = new Locale("gsw");
```

The `de-CH` language tag is an alternative way to create a "Swiss German" tag - and this is the tag referred to by that page referenced in the question.

But there is also [this other page](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/gsw/index.html) for the ICU "gsw" locale. On *this* page, the grouping separator is the `’` right single quotation mark. It's hard to tell, just by looking at the page - but if you copy/paste to a monospace font, you will see the difference.

### Java Code Examples

Looking at Java, we can write the following:

```
double d = 12345.67;
// This line is just so my console prints out the correct UTF-8 characters:
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Locale swissGermanLocale = new Locale("gsw");
//Locale swissGermanLocale = new Locale("de", "CH");
out.println(swissGermanLocale.getDisplayName());  // Swiss German

final NumberFormat gswFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(swissGermanLocale);

// Find out what the grouping separator is for the given locale:
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(swissGermanLocale);
char c = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
out.println(c);  // ’

out.println(gswFormat.format(d));  // 12’345.67
```

Note that the locale based on `gsw` is called "Swiss German".

The locale based on `de-CH` is called "German (Switzerland)". A subtle difference.

Regardless, the end result is that numbers use the `’` separator, not the standard apostrophe.

As mentioned at the start of this answer, it's possible you may want/need to use `'` as your separator, as a conscious change from the "official" locale format. If so, then you can use the decimal format object, as you mention.